# Spark SQL: how to cache sql query result without using rdd.cache()

Tags: caching, query-optimization, apache-spark

Is there any way to cache a cache sql query result without using rdd.cache()?
for examples:

```
output = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * From people")
```

We can use **output.cache()** to cache the result, but then we cannot use sql query to deal with it.

So I want to ask is there anything like sqlcontext.cacheTable() to cache the result?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `sqlContext.cacheTable("table_name")` in order to cache it, or alternatively use `CACHE TABLE table_name` SQL query.

Here's an example. I've got this file on HDFS:

```
1|Alex|alex@gmail.com
2|Paul|paul@example.com
3|John|john@yahoo.com
```

Then the code in PySpark:

```
people = sc.textFile('hdfs://sparkdemo:8020/people.txt')
people_t = people.map(lambda x: x.split('|')).map(lambda x: Row(id=x[0], name=x[1], email=x[2]))
tbl = sqlContext.inferSchema(people_t)
tbl.registerTempTable('people')
```

Now we have a table and can query it:

```
sqlContext.sql('select * from people').collect()
```

To persist it, we have 3 options:

```
# 1st - using SQL
sqlContext.sql('CACHE TABLE people').collect()
# 2nd - using SQLContext
sqlContext.cacheTable('people')
sqlContext.sql('select count(*) from people').collect()     
# 3rd - using Spark cache underlying RDD
tbl.cache()
sqlContext.sql('select count(*) from people').collect()
```

1st and 2nd options are preferred as they would cache the data in optimized in-memory columnar format, while 3rd would cache it just as any other RDD in row-oriented fashion

So going back to your question, here's one possible solution:

```
output = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * From people")
output.registerTempTable('people2')
sqlContext.cacheTable('people2')
sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) From people2").collect()
```

Comment: "Spark SQL can cache tables using an in-memory columnar format by calling spark.catalog.cacheTable("tableName") or dataFrame.cache()." (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching-data-in-memory) . The documentation seems to imply that 1st, 2nd and 3rd option are all equivalent.

Comment: The dicumentation is all over the place

Answer (score 9):

The following is most like using .cache for RDDs and helpful in Zeppelin or similar SQL-heavy-environments

```
CACHE TABLE CACHED_TABLE AS
SELECT $interesting_query
```

then you get cached reads both for subsequent usages of `interesting_query`, as well as on all queries on `CACHED_TABLE`.

This answer is based off of the accepted answer, but the power of using `AS` is what really made the call useful in the more constrained SQL-only environments, where you cannot `.collect()` or do RDD/Dataframe-operations in any way.

Comment: To me, this is the most powerful feature of Spark ! Especially for JOIN operations.