# Caching DataFrame in Spark Thrift Server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-thriftserver

I have a Spark Thrift Server. I connect to the Thrift Server and get data of Hive table. If I query the same table again, it will again load the file in memory and execute the query.

Is there any way I can cache the table data using Spark Thrift Server? If yes, please let me know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- use `CACHE LAZY TABLE` as in this answer: [Spark SQL: how to cache sql query result without using rdd.cache()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027160/spark-sql-how-to-cache-sql-query-result-without-using-rdd-cache) and [cache tables in apache spark sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419410/cache-tables-in-apache-spark-sql)
- use `spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession=true` so that other clients can use this cached table.

Remember that caching is lazy, so it will be cached during first computation

Comment: Is there any UI or something to see the cached table?

Comment: @AdityaCalangutkar It will be visible on the Storage tab of Spark UI, however as a RDD not DataFrame or Dataset

Comment: Can you control the cache via SQL (like persist method do) ? (Memory / Disk)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that memory could be consumed by the Driver, not the executor (depend on your settings, local/cluster ...), so don't forget to allocate more memory to your driver.

To put in data:

```
CACHE TABLE today AS
SELECT * FROM datahub WHERE year=2017 AND fullname IN ("api.search.search") LIMIT 40000
```

Start by limiting the data, then look how memory is consumed to avoid OOM exception.

[image: Spark history web UI]

Comment: Pls clarify driver comment. You mean for collect I presume?